# php script stops dead on some valid mssql queries

Tags: php, sql-server

I created a script to perform a few select queries on a mssql database, but the script seems to stop dead on certain queries, without returning any errors. The browser receives a completely empty response from the server. On Firefox, it prompts to download a blank .php file; on Chrome it returns "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): Unknown error."; and on IE8 it returns "Page cannot be displayed".

The query is

```
$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM EmployeeHours
    WHERE (EmployeeId = '".$staff_id."')
    AND (TimeIn > DATEADD(second, ".$week_start.", CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01', 102)))
    AND (TimeOut < DATEADD(second, ".$week_end.", CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01', 102))
        OR TimeOut IS NULL)
    ORDER BY UTCDateAdded DESC";
$query = mssql_query($sql);
```

$staff_id is a simple int. $week_start and $week_end are unix timestamps.

I don't think it's the query itself, because it runs fine in MSSQL Server Management Studio and returns the correct data. I can also simplify the query down to "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM EmployeeHours" with no WHERE conditions and it still fails.

Setting error_reporting to E_ALL has no effect. It doesn't execute anything past the mssql_query(). Anything printed or echoed before the query doesn't appear in the resulting file either.

I can verify that it is connected to the the correct database, because I can run some other queries on tables in the same database and get results through the script.

Comment: Every time you create sql with unescaped `$variable`s, God kills a kitten.

Comment: @cHao They are escaped before the bit of the script that I posted.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the MSSQL extension, it's not available since PHP 5.3, you can use the official Microsoft driver [SQLSRV](http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/) (here you have the [API doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296152%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)) which is much more feature-rich but have some weird problems, like most of the Microsoft API's.

Comment: What web server? (IIS? Apache?) What does the web server's error log say? I've seen a problem like this before when a script I wrote was actually causing Apache to segfault - thus the response was never fully sent.

Comment: @NuclearDog Apache. Error log doesn't show me anything from that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried switching to the [ODBC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php) extension instead of MSSQL ext and it would hang when using select queries with odbc_exec(). Found no fix for that either.

Finally got it to work by switching to [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is date type in result, use cast for date data types.
Example:
SELECT my_day, other_field FROM my_table
use
SELECT convert(varchar(19), my_day, 120) as my_day, other_field FROM my_table

use format your preference

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was retrieving a float, a varchar(2) , two longs, and a "money" using PDO (dblib).  The money value that was causing this was negative - a credit.  I ended up changing the money field to a float, and the query would execute without the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.  Hopefully this will shorten someone else's time spent on this issue!